# Powershell command to tell if TeamCity Build Agents are running?

Tags: powershell, selenium, webdriver, teamcity, build-agent

We have a server that has TeamCity installed. Is there any way to run a powershell command from that server to tell if the BuildAgents are currently all `Idle`?

Basically, we have acceptance tests that aren't tearing down `geckodriver` and `firefox` properly. I'm currently manually remoting to the server to kill them.

Obviously, the proper solution is to figure out which tests aren't tearing down... but this could be a nice short-term automation.

Comment: I don't know anything about TeamCity... can you put in a step either at the start or end of your automation run where you just kill all browser drivers? That's what we do with TFS.

Comment: @JeffC We could... it would be a pain because we have atleast 25+ places we'd have to add that buildstep. Not a bad idea though